# asp.net mvc disable list box

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can i disable the list box

```
Html.ListBox("Organization", Model.OrgListbox as MultiSelectList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the htmlAttributes parameter:

```
Html.ListBox("Organization", Model.OrgListbox as MultiSelectList, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the disabled attribute to the HTML then you would do this:

```
Html.ListBox("Organization", Model.OrgListbox as MultiSelectList, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

This calls the overload of Html.ListBox where you can specify htmlAttributes that are added to the rendered HTML.

Alternatively you could use jQuery, doing something like this:

```
$("#controlId).attr("disabled","disabled");
```